# Using Scrapy to to find and download multiple pdfs files from a website

Tags: python, pdf, scrapy

I need to download multiple pdf files from a website using Scrapy. I'm  new to Python, and Scrapy is a very new to me. I've been experimenting with the console and a few rudimentary spiders.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import requests

class ToScrapeCSSSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "toscrape-css2"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for actions in response.css("div.action-item"):
                condition = actions.css("a::attr(data-jalios-id)").extract_first()
                if condition is not None:
                    yield {
                    'data-jalios-id': actions.css("a::attr(data-jalios-id)").extract_first(),
                    'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id='+str(actions.css("a::attr(data-jalios-id)").extract_first()),
                     }
                    targeturl = 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id='+str(actions.css("a::attr(data-jalios-id)").extract_first())
                    pdf_response = requests.get(targeturl)

            # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
                    if pdf_response.status_code == 200:
                # Specify where to save the PDF on your local machine
                # You can customize the path and filename as needed
                        filename = targeturl.split('/')[-1]
                        with open(filename, 'wb') as pdf_file:
                         pdf_file.write(pdf_response.content)
                        self.log(f'Saved {filename}')
                else:
                        self.log(f'Failed to download {targeturl}')
        next_page_url = response.css("li.next > a::attr(href)").extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))
```

I run this code at the command line with
`scrapy crawl toscrape-css2`

and I get this back which is not what I expected

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py:6: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography will remove support for Python 3.6.
  from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.6.3 started (bot: quotesbot)
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.3.0, libxml2 2.9.13, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 2.0.1, Twisted 21.2.0, Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:41:53) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)], pyOpenSSL 23.2.0 (OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023), cryptography 40.0.2, Platform Darwin-22.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'quotesbot',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'quotesbot.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['quotesbot.spiders']}
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: dde77b5c38a7cc3d
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 4446323264 on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 4446323264 acquired on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 4446324048 on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/urls/62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 4446324048 acquired on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/urls/62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 4446324048 on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/urls/62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 4446324048 released on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/urls/62bf135d1c2f3d4db4228b9ecaf507a2.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 4446323264 on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 4446323264 released on /Users/alexismathieu/.cache/python-tldextract/3.6.5.final__3.6__a9d949__tldextract-3.1.2/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.has-sante.fr/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 4 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 6 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 10 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 14 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 26 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 37 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 38 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 40 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 42 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 43 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 44 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 72 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 90 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 128 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 132 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:04 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 139 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines> (referer: None)
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_2773626', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626'}
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626 HTTP/1.1" 200 364
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1695400', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400'}
2023-09-19 21:34:10 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400 HTTP/1.1" 200 376
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1637246', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246'}
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246 HTTP/1.1" 200 477
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1105132', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105132'}
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105132 HTTP/1.1" 200 416
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105132
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105132
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1105136', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105136'}
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105136 HTTP/1.1" 200 408
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105136
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105136
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1005124', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124'}
2023-09-19 21:34:11 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124 HTTP/1.1" 200 409
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1005132', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132'}
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132 HTTP/1.1" 200 410
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_644452', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452'}
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452 HTTP/1.1" 200 397
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_727079', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_727079'}
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_727079 HTTP/1.1" 200 444
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_727079
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_727079
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_644450', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450'}
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450 HTTP/1.1" 200 381
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_426790', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790'}
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790 HTTP/1.1" 200 381
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_269911', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911'}
2023-09-19 21:34:12 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911 HTTP/1.1" 200 378
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_461116 HTTP/1.1" 200 381
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_461116
2023-09-19 21:34:13 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_461116
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2> (referer: https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines)
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_2773626', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626'}
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626 HTTP/1.1" 200 364
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_2773626
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1695400', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400'}
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400 HTTP/1.1" 200 376
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1695400
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1637246', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246'}
2023-09-19 21:34:19 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246 HTTP/1.1" 200 477
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1637246
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1105132', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1105132'}
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124 HTTP/1.1" 200 409
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005124
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_1005132', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132'}
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132 HTTP/1.1" 200 410
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_1005132
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_644452', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452'}
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452 HTTP/1.1" 200 397
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644452
2023-09-19 21:34:20 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:22 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450 HTTP/1.1" 200 381
2023-09-19 21:34:22 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450
2023-09-19 21:34:22 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_644450
2023-09-19 21:34:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_426790', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790'}
2023-09-19 21:34:22 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790 HTTP/1.1" 200 381
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_426790
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_269911', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911'}
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.has-sante.fr:443
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://www.has-sante.fr:443 "GET /plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911 HTTP/1.1" 200 378
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Saved doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [toscrape-css2] DEBUG: Failed to download https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_269911
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2>
{'data-jalios-id': 'c_835620', 'targeturl': 'https://www.has-sante.fr/plugins/ModuleXitiKLEE/types/FileDocument/doXiti.jsp?id=c_835620'}
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875171/fr/resultat-de-recherche?FACET_THEME=c_64654%2Fc_64672%2Fc_1151685&types=guidelines&page=2> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1104,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 60821,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 19.286613,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 19, 19, 34, 23, 539884),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 247994,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 2,
 'item_scraped_count': 28,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 173,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 55140352,
 'memusage/startup': 55140352,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 19, 19, 34, 4, 253271)}
2023-09-19 21:34:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

It seems there is something downloaded but it's not pdf files.

Comment: there is no `div#all_results` on the page you are trying to scrape.  You cant just copy code and enter a new url and hope it will work....

Comment: @Alexander I have modified the code to match the target page css. Scraping works but the downloaded files are not expected pdf. Any experience with that ?

Answer (score 0):

For downloading music you can should use default media pipeline https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

It will look somethink like this (but the code may need improvement):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from scrapy.http import Request

class pwc_tax(scrapy.Spider):
name = "pdfspider"

allowed_domains = ["www.has-sante.fr"]
start_urls = ["https://www.has-sante.fr/jcms/fc_2875208/fr/rechercher-une-recommandation-un-avis?histstate=1"]

custom_settings = {
    'FILES_URLS_FIELD': 'file_urls',
    'FILES_RESULT_FIELD': 'files',
    'FILES_STORE': 'media/pdf_files',
    'MEDIA_URL': '/media/',
    'MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS': True,
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'scrapy.pipelines.media.MediaPipeline': 1,
    }
}

def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.css('div#all_results h3 a::attr(href)').extract():
        yield Request(
            url=response.urljoin(href),
            callback=self.parse_article
        )

def parse_article(self, response):
    item = {}
    item['file_urls'] = response.css('div.download_wrapper a[href$=".pdf"]::attr(href)').extract()
    yield item
```